# Render settings for 2d animation in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, 2d

What are the best render settings for a 2d animation comprising of flat geometric shapes in Blender, either 2.79 or 2.8? I have tried various things in both and the results are poor with the shapes stuttering across the screen. Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Never had that sort of problem with 2D animation. Please provide examples. What output settings are you using? Try a very small render size for quick tests e.g. 640x480 just to see speed etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll try a small version as you suggest.

Comment: Meanwhile, here is a link to some test files with my original settings  <https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mo49331n7uuz94x/AADrSv0pTZo-STdic8ENdPSoa?dl=0>  Also, someone suggested the following settings which I tried but with no improvement:     File Format - FFmpeg Video.

Container - Matroska

Video Codec - H.264

Output Quality Perceptually Lossless

Keyframe Interval - 1

Comment: Okay, I've tried rendering at  640x480  - its not a great result either.  I've uploaded the files to the link above.

Comment: I am not seeing any stuttering in the video you just uploaded or in the results from the .blend. If you are talking about the image quality then you can increase the Output Quality to Lossless.

Comment: I've just realised that when I play the movie file online from drop box, the result appears better than when I play the file offline, though it isn't consistent. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: no, what is the player on your local machine? I use VLC

Comment: Its an open source player called 'Videos'.  I've also played it on someone else's windows 10 computer using the default player (not sure what it is called these days) and had the same issues.  Perhaps I should try with VLC

Comment: I always recommend VLC, works with just about everything. Watch out for dodgy download sites, https://www.videolan.org/vlc/